# How can adverbial locutions function as restrictive modifiers in Portuguese?

Tags: gramática

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, I need some grammar wizard for this. I'm writing an essay on Portuguese grammar but there's one bit that I've been stuck on.

Im explaining how a locução adverbial can be used to describe nouns. And I emailed Ciberduvidas* with the same question and I know now that they can describe nouns because they are modificadores restritivos. The question I have, and which I've been thinking about for about a day, is how a Locução adverbial can be considered a modificadores restritivo because I'm not sure which of the listed criteria they fall under, namely:

> Os elementos que podem funcionar como modificadores restritivos do
> nome podem ser grupos adjectivais (ii), grupos preposicionais (iii) ou
> orações subordinadas adjectivas (iv).

Because it doesn't mention "locução adverbial" in that list, I suppose it has to be one of the other ones.

> *As locuções adverbiais podem ser empregadas para modificar nomes (substantivos), isto é, podem funcionar como modificadores
> restritivos, tal como acontece mais geralmente com os adjetivos.
>
> Como se lê, por exemplo, no Dicionário Terminológico, documento de
> apoio ao ensino da gramática no ensino não superior em Portugal:
>
> «[...] Os elementos que podem funcionar como modificadores restritivos
> do nome podem ser grupos adjectivais (ii), grupos preposicionais (iii)
> ou orações subordinadas adjectivas (iv).
>
> Exemplos:
>
> [...]
>
> (ii) Adoro [flores [frescas e coloridas]].
>
> (iii) [O rapaz [de barba]] é meu aluno.
>
> (iv) [Os lobos [que vivem no Parque Peneda-Gerês]] estão em vias de
> extinção.» (https://dt.dge.mec.pt/index.php?id=n305)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think adverbs can modify nouns, though they can modify pronouns, I think. All explanations of adverbs I've seen don't say they can modify nouns.

Comment: @Schilive Adverbs cant but a locução adverbial can. For example, in one of the suggested questions I got when submitting my question, someone asked about the locução adverbial "ao vivo". It is used to modify the noun "transmissão"

Comment: Please fix your punctuation and apostrophes. If you are writing a grammar book, you can't do us the honor of writing "can't" instead of "cant" and "I'm".

Comment: In English: adverbial phrase, I would say, rather than locution. In Portuguese ao vivo can be an adjective or viewed as an adverbial phrase modifier. Also, restrictive modifier is just a modifier in English: The small children, the big children. Those adjectives are called restrictive in Portuguese....

Comment: I worked hard on this answer so it would be really nice if you responded.

Comment: @Lambie Sure, I will be more contentious of my grammar. Although given your comments are rife with errors, one would do well to tread lightly before maligning the grammatical errors of others.

Comment: First, I did not say anything about grammatical errors. I said punctuation and apostrophes. Second, I doubt you mean contentious. Three, please see my new comment under my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what a **locução adverbial** (adverbial phrase) is in Portuguese:

There's a huge list of them by category:

Locução adverbial de tempo: em breve, logo mais, à tarde, à noite, pela manhã, por vezes, de tempos em tempos etc.
Locução adverbial de lugar: em cima, por perto, ao lado, à direita, à esquerda, para dentro, para fora etc.
Locução adverbial de afirmação: por certo, sem dúvida, com certeza, na verdade, de fato etc.
Locução adverbial de negação: de forma alguma, de modo algum, de maneira nenhuma etc.
Locução adverbial de modo: às pressas, ao contrário, em silêncio, de cor, às claras, à toa, em geral etc.
Locução adverbial de quantidade: de muito, de pouco, de todo, em excesso etc.

These are taken from [o mundo da educação](https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/locucao-adverbial.htm)

So, this statement:
*As locuções adverbiais podem ser empregadas para modificar nomes (substantivos), isto é, podem funcionar como modificadores restritivos, tal como acontece mais geralmente com os adjetivos.

is a true statement.

So, if you say: "**O rapaz à esquerda** é meu aluno". **à esquerda** is considered an adverbial phrase in Portuguese.
OR
"As **flores [qui estão] de perto** parecem frescas e coloridas. Same idea. de perto is considered an adverbial phrase.

OR
Os meninos **de cima** são teimosos.

A modificador restritivo do nome is just a noun adjunct or modifier. Flores **pequenas.**

**Whereas if you use one of those adverbial phrases with the noun in Portuguese, it is considered an adverbial phrase in Portuguese grammar and not adjectival.
The **upstairs** bedroom in English has **upstairs** as an **adjective.**
Notice  the translation:

O quarto **de cima** in Portuguese is an adverbial phrase modifying the noun quarto.

It is also um modificador restritivo. So basically, we are dealing with a nomenclature thing. Much of what is called an adverbial phrase in Portuguese would be called adjective or noun adjunct in English.

Well, I guess I muddled through that OK. :) Bear in mind that some adverbial   phrases in English can also modify nouns.

Comment: Thanks! Thats very helpful. Although, I was specifically wondering about how a locução adverbial qualifies as a restrictive modifier given the criteria of what can comprise a restrictive modifier "grupos adjectivais (ii), grupos preposicionais (iii) ou orações subordinadas adjectivas (iv)." And locução adverbial is not on that list. But I emailed  them again because it was really bothering me and the answer is that its part of the  "grupos adjectivais"

Comment: Lambie, does that mean that *lá*, *cá*, *aqui* etc. can modify a noun? as in “o cachorro lá [apontando] é fofo”.

Comment: A locuçao adverbial can be part of any one of those. As locução adverbial just means words like: de cima, de baixo, etc. See the list in my answer. A **menina bonita de cima** mora em outra casa. **de cima** =locução adverbial. **menina bonita** =modificador restritivo. Another: Dentro dos padrões em geral, os diretores [etc]. **Dentros dos padrôes em geral** is a **grupo preposicional** that includes em geral which is a locução adverbial.

Comment: @Schilive No, it does not. lá, cá, aqui etc. are not on locuçôes adverbiais.  Please look at the list. Those are just regular adverbs.

Comment: @Lambie, what is *lá* modifying in "o cachorro lá é fofo"? I can't see it.

Comment: @Schilive **It isn't modifying** anything. It is an adverb of place in relation to the speaker. It can also be called a deictic marker.

Comment: @Lambie, thanks.